# ValueError: Unknown initializer with clone_model and custom initialization

Tags: tensorflow

I created the minimum working example. You can reproduce it [here](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/NEGU93/32cf93d9b9b7908c492a68e6fc93cd05/clone_model_custom_init.ipynb)

I created my own Initializer called `ComplexGlorotUniform(Initializer)`.

Then I created a file like: `init_dispatcher = {"complex_glorot_uniform": ComplexGlorotUniform()}`

Finally, I did:

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import get_custom_objects

get_custom_objects().update(init_dispatcher)
```

I generated a sequential model of `Dense` layers using `kernel_initializer="complex_glorot_uniform"`.

Now when using `tf.keras.models.clone_model` I get the error:

```
ValueError: Unknown initializer: ComplexGlorotUniform. Please ensure this object is passed to the `custom_objects` argument. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#registering_the_custom_object
```

I DO think the `custom_object` is working correctly because he knows it's ComplexGlorotUniform and not the string I gave. Also, the layer is created correctly, is when calling the clone model method that it gets broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am still unsure why but I solved it by changing the `init_dispatcher` to `init_dispatcher = {"ComplexGlorotUniform": ComplexGlorotUniform}` to make the name match the string.

I guess it is Ok as it works for me but I am unsure if this is how it is supposed to work.